# Send data from layout to controller Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controller

I have a switch button on my navbar on my layout view, when I click the button It changes the value and send it to the controller:

```
<input type="button" id="switchbutton" value="Weekend" style="color:blue" onclick="toggle(this)" >

<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle(button) {
        switch (button.value) {
            case "Weekend":
                button.value = "Week";
                break;
            case "Week":
                button.value = "Weekend";
                break;
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/AjaxMethod",
            data: '{param: "' + $(this).val() + '" }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
                alert("Return Value: " + response);
            },
            failure: function(response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            error: function(response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

On the controller I receive the value and send it to an If statement that executes a function depending on the value received.

```
private string SwitchVal;
[HttpPost]
public string AjaxMethod(string param)
{
    var d = string.Empty;
    switch (param)
    {
        case "Weekend":
            d = "Week";
            break;
        case "Week":
            d = "Weekend";
            break;
    }
    SwitchVal = d;
    return d;
}

public JsonResult ModelsUpdate(string SwitchVal)
{
    if (SwitchVal == "Weekend")
    {
        resultminDate = CalculateminDate(minDate, todayDay);
    }
    else
    {
        resultminDate = CalculateminDateWeek(minDate, todayDay);
    }
```

The problem is that I do click on the button and I don't see any change, It seems that the value only arrives to the controller the first time. Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: The  private `SwitchVal` variable will not hold data between 2 http calls.

Comment: What is happening now ? Is it making the ajax call ? Are you getting a script error ?

Comment: "I don't see any change" what is the expected change ?

Comment: @Shyju The SwitchVal variable is outside both functions, why It won't keep the value?

Comment: @rainman The value is used on an if statement that runs on function or another and those functions returns differnt data, but I always see the same values

Comment: @Shyju I'm not receiving an error, when I debug I can see that SwitchVal has the value but I think it only receive it on the first click

Comment: Because http is stateless. If you want the value to be stored between 2 calls, you need to use some persistent mechanism (Ex : database/ Session storage /static field etc)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work like that. You can't hold the values in server side for multiple different requests. Maybe you can use `Session` to perform it but why don't you post the data `ModelsUpdate` action instead of `AjaxMethod`. In your case, I couldn't understand the purpose of `AjaxMethod`.

```
    public JsonResult ModelsUpdate(string SwitchVal)
    {
        if (SwitchVal == "Weekend")
        {
            resultminDate = CalculateminDate(minDate, todayDay);
        }
        else
        {
            resultminDate = CalculateminDateWeek(minDate, todayDay);
        }
        return Json(resultminDate);
    }
```

`Ajax` call looks like

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Home/ModelsUpdate",
    data: '{SwitchVal: "' + $(this).val() + '" }',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        alert("Return Value: " + response);
    },
    failure: function(response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
    },
    error: function(response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi,

I did it and i don't have errors but my problem is still the same, the view data doesn't change when I click on the button

Comment: You are performing just alert message when the request is completed succesfully. What would you expect ?

Comment: No, I have the value returned in an If statement that runs a function depending on the value returned. Please check on the code.

Comment: I understand what you say now, I need to refresh my view with the new dataset

Comment: How can I refresh my index view with the new data?

Comment: You can't refresh the view like that.It is more complicated. You should create a partial view and return it as Ajax result instead of json. So, if you have bit process on the client side I suggest you to use javacript/Jquery to perform it loading again whole partial view instead.